# AutoMapper getting maps mixed up when running large number of tests?

Tags: unity-container, automapper, mstest

I currently have a solution with about 1000 unit/integration tests using MSTest runner. The problem Im experiencing with AutoMapper is that when I have VS run all tests in the solution, I'll randomly get a few unit tests fail due to the following automapper exception:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

Mapping types:
String -> String
System.String -> System.String

Destination path:
CatalogResource.CultureCode

Source value:
en-US ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Model.Catalog' to type 'Model.CatalogResource'.
```

In the code I dont have a Catalog to CatalogResource map nor am I trying to map them to each other. This type of exception doesnt happen in PROD, doesnt happen for the integration tests, doesnt happen every time I run the tests and when it does happen, it is always different tests that fail. Also, if I run only the tests that just failed, they always pass. I have a hard time consistently reproducing this locally but it happens more frequently on the build server, which is a pain because it prevents the build from getting automatically promoted to the next environment.

I've also tried adding this to the tests but it has not solved the problem:

```
   [ClassInitialize]
   public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
   {
        Mapper.Reset();
   }
```

Any ideas? We've had 4 different people take a stab at this to no avail so Im resorting to you great folks for help now.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I currently initialize the configuration using a static class that gets called inside a static constructor for the service. I.E.

```
static MyService()
        {
            AutoMapperBootstrapper.Initialize();
        }
...

internal static class AutoMapperBootstrapper
    {
 public static void Initialize()
        {
            ConfigureMappings();

            #if DEBUG
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            #endif
        }
}
```

EDIT #2:

While doing some more tinkering today, I notice that these random failures happen only for `<IDataReader, something else>` maps. For example:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Catalog>()
            .ForMember(m => m.CatalogID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["CatalogID"]))               
            .ForMember(m => m.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Title"]))                   
            .ForMember(m => m.DateCreatedUTC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["DateCreatedUTC"]))
            .ForMember(m => m.DateModifiedUTC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["DateModifiedUTC"]))
```

...

Not sure what to make of it yet but it seemed relevant.

Comment: How do you initialise the AutoMapper configuration (via profiles, during app start, IoC, etc)? Do you check your mappings with [AssertConfigurationIsValid](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation)?

Comment: I added an edit to the question. Yes, I am asserting configuration and Im initializing it via the static constructor for the service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you call `AutoMapperBootstrapper.Initialize` from your unit tests, and the ONLY location you have the mapping configuration is in `ConfigureMappings`? I can't explain your issue, but you obviously have some leakage between your unit tests somewhere. I have a similar setup, and this is what I do...

My initialisation code is

```cs
public static class MappingConfiguration
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<MapperProfileOne>();
                x.AddProfile<MapperProfileTwo>();
            });
    }
}
```

This is only ever called by the application (I dont bother testing the `RegisterMappings` method as it only has the single `Initialize` call and I trust that `AutoMapper` works. My unit tests (to test my mapping configuration) are as follows:

```cs
[Test]
public void Initialise_ProfileOne_GeneratesNoErrors()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<MapperProfileOne>());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}

[Test]
public void Initialise_ProfileTwo_GeneratesNoErrors()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<MapperProfileTwo>());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

An example of a profile is:

```cs
public class MapperProfileOne : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering that if you're calling the `AutoMapperBootstrapper` method from your unit tests that its somehow getting confused (there's not enough detail in the question to determine this for certain). I don't think it should, but hopefully there's at least something in the code above that might magically fix the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I dont call the initialize directly from the unit test but when the unit test news up an instance of the service, the static constructor will get called and the AutoMapperBootstrapper will get triggered. What kind of detail do you think could help? I added a second edit with something I think is relevant but Im not sure what to make of it. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be initialising AutoMapper in the service, you should only do it the once (eg, in `Application_Start` for a web app) - this is where I think your unit tests are getting a little tongue tied. Then try calling `ConfigureMappings();` directly in your unit tests (or ideally just initialise the profile/mapping you need).